# How do i add a button in the window layout in the google fusion table?

Tags: google-fusion-tables

How do i add a button in the window layout in the google fusion table? I want to get the direction from a particular point to the point when i click on the button "GO".
(https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/infowindow_driving_directions)

Is it possible to add a script in custom window layout? I want to add these feature to this page.
I add this in the custom window layout.

```
<div class='googft-info-window' style='font-family: sans-serif'>
<b>FamilyID:</b> {FamilyID}<br>
<b>FamilyHead:</b> {FamilyHead}<br>
<b>Ward:</b> {Ward}<br>
Get direction : <input type="button">Go</button>
</div>
```

The button is not show..Link to my fusion table is given below.

https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1cabvZOod51ubZI815QTLL8Py2CM4DWkSE3E3Pds&pli=1#map:id=3

Regards,
Zacharia Cherian

Comment: *Is it possible to add a script in custom window layout?*

After 16hours the answer ist still: NO -> https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/google-fusion-tables/how-do-i/A1LjwQmzbU4

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is incorrect.

```
<input type="button" value="Go">
```

But you will probably want to have it actually do something also.

Answer (score 0):

There are two different ways to specify info window content: (1) within the Fusion Tables UI / info window template  (2) after click, using Javascript and the Google Maps API to specify info window content.

Method (1) does not accept scripts. You won't be able to make your button work. 
Method (2) will support your button. However, you can't do it in the Fusion Tables UI. You'll have to set your map up as a Fusion Tables Layer with the Google Maps API (FusionTableslayer wizard can help), then suppress the Fusion Tables info windows and specify your own info window content. Please refer to the [sample code](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/infowindow_driving_directions) for a model of how to do this.

-Rebecca